# Удалил файлы через git revert. Как восстановить?

Tags: git, github

Столкнулся с проблемой закомител файлы а потом сделал git revert и файлы удалились.
Как их восстановить?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, текстовую информацию прикладывайте в виде текста, а не скриншотами, чтобы текст можно было копировать и чтобы работал поиск.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вы сделали только `git reflog` и после этого `git commit`, то ваши файлы не удалились, а просто проект перешёл в другое состояние, команда `git revert` создала новый коммит с отменёнными изменениями, а прежний коммит остался в истории.

При помощи команды `git reflog` находите ваш HEAD-коммит и затем используя

`git reset --hard HEAD@{номер_коммита}` откатываетесь к нужному состоянию